# Angular inside existing .NET Core MVC solution not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I got an existing solution in .NET Core MVC that I wanted to use Angular in a specific view, but not everywhere.

Therefore I used the command line to create a new Angular application inside the solution in a folder called Angular.

## The structure is:

**SelfService (Project)**

- Angular
- - src (all other angular structure here also in this level)
- Views
- - Dashboard
- - - Dashboard.cshtml

There is a feature switch to let it be eased in by pilots trying it out.

I use the feature of proxy because Angular development server is running port 4200, and my applications port is running port 44323. So using proxy to fix that on my local machine.

I have set it up, which works very well when running the development server and going to "http://localhost:4200", but when I go to /dashboard in the existing solution it loads the same view, but the clicks and updates doesn't work. It simply does nothing

## **Startup.cs *(Part of)***

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

// In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "Angular/dist";
            });
}

public void Configure
{
app.UseStaticFiles();

 app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

app.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    spa.Options.SourcePath = "Angular";

                    if (env.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                    }
                    // Doesn't work so using a bat-file running ng serve and then works
                    //if (env.IsDevelopment())
                    //{
                    //    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                    //}
                });
}
```

## **Dashboard.cshtml**

```
@if (ViewBag.IsAngularDasboardFeaturesEnabled)
                        {
                            <app-root>app-root is loading ...</app-root>
                        }

.....

@section EndContent {
    @if (ViewBag.IsAngularDasboardFeaturesEnabled)
    {
        @if (hostingEnv.IsDevelopment())
        {
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/runtime.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/styles.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/vendor.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/main.js"></script>
        }
        else
        {
            <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/AngularOutput/main.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/AngularOutput/polyfills.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/AngularOutput/runtime.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/AngularOutput/styles.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/AngularOutput/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        }
    }
```

## **app.component.html**

```
<div (click)="clickHandler()">
  {{title}}
</div>
```

## **app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  counter: number = 1;
  title = 'Angular LAWE (You are the BOSSmann)' + this.counter;

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("hello");
      this.title = "something else"; 
    }, 5000);
  }

  clickHandler(): any {
    console.log("Change click", ++this.counter);
    this.title = "hi" + this.counter;
  }
}
```

I would expect that when it works in with the development server for http://localhost:4200, then it would also work for https://localhost:44323/dashboard/ but it doesn't.

<strike>?? Can it be the problem of https vs http?</strike>

**UPDATE 1:** I have used in Angular application folder in package.json "start": "ng serve --ssl true", which removed the WDS-error, but now gives GET https://localhost/runtime.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

?? When my development server from VS in Startup.cs doesn't work, could that be the reason why the clicks and everything doesn't work? It renders the component, and writes logs from init, and I can call the clickMethod that logs clicked, but clicking the div doesn't work.

**UPDATE 2:** Changed the port to be the local developments port instead of 4200, but gave a 500 response instead.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What does your console look like when you're on the page?

Comment: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

Comment: VM3357:1 GET https://localhost:44323/sockjs-node/info?t=1558360806120 500
(anonymous) @ VM3357:1
scheduleTask @ zone.js:3243
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:238
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:261
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1245
(anonymous) @ zone.js:3276
proto.<computed> @ zone.js:1569
AbstractXHRObject._start @ sockjs.js:1605
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:1494

Comment: zone.js:423
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:487
timer @ zone.js:2281
setTimeout (async)
InfoReceiver @ sockjs.js:524
SockJS @ sockjs.js:730
initSocket @ socket.js:9
(anonymous) @ client:212
./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0 @ vendor.js:87160
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
client:177 [WDS] Disconnected!

Comment: That's the only things I got in the console, but it displays the components as they should be.
They doesn't show "App root is loading..."

Comment: I got this from this request: https://localhost:44323/sockjs-node/info?t=1558362937483
  Failed to start 'npm'.
  I figured out that I could add _"--ssl true"_ to the "start" inside package.json, so it ended being
  **"start": "ng serve --ssl true",**
  
  This gave that I didn't get the **[WDS] Disconnected! message**.
  Sadly I now get this error in console:
  _**http://localhost:4200/runtime.js net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if I copied the markup to another controller and another view everything worked out fine.
It was the combination of Knockout mixed with Angular that made it not work.

```
<!-- ko if: selectedAreaTabFound() === 1 -->
<app-root>app-root is loading ...</app-root>
<!-- /ko -->
```

So the click events was working if it wasn't combined with Knockout, and routing and all events could fire if it was in a new page.
Eventually I scraped everything away and it came down to removing all the knockout comments around it for it to work.
So now I have to think about another way to make it work where I wanted it, but I found the problem.